# rerender rich:tab contnet

Tags: jsp, jsf, richfaces, jsf-2

I have try to provide the web2.0 support for my application.For that i wants to provide the rich:tabpanel that can contains number of tabs dynamically.User can add and remove the tabs.For that i use c:foreach for represent the list of rich:tab.The tab contains list of rich:panel contains the details.The panel contains only brief content.By clicking the read more link,the user can read full content.For that i need to rerender the a4j:outputpanel which contains the list of rich:panel.But i can't do this.Because i have used c:freach for render the list of tabs.So i can't get the exact id of the a4j:outputpanel which contains list rich:panels.The a4j:outputpanel doesnot allowed the el expressions.My code snippet is below,

```
<c:forEach items="#{Home.tabList}" var="homeBean" varStatus="status">
<el:define value="${status.count}" var="rowIndex"/>
 <rich:tab id="homeTab" label="#{homeBean.header}"
                        name="#{homeBean.header}" switchType="client"
                        onlabelclick="coinSliderFunction('coin-slider#{rowIndex}')">
<a4j:outputPanel id="subHeaderPanel">
<h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3"
 id="detailGrid"                                                                   rendered="#{!Home.subHeaderDetailedContentPanelRendered}"
                                                                   columnClasses="layoutContentColumnClass,
                                                                     layoutContentColumnClass,layoutContentColumnClass">

 <%--SubHeader List--%>
 <c:forEach items="#{homeBean.subHeaderBeanList}" var="subHeaderBean" varStatus="subHeaderStatus">
  <rich:panel header="#{subHeaderBean.header}" id="subHeaderPanels">
 <h:outputText id="outputText" value="#{subHeaderBean.briefContent}" escape="false"/>
  <a4j:commandLink value="Read More" id="readMoreLink" 
action="#{Home.navigationHandler}" reRender="subHeaderPanel">    
 <a4j:actionparam name="headerActionParam" value="#{homeBean.header}" assignTo="#{Home.headerName}"/>
<a4j:actionparam name="subHeaderActionParam" value="#{subHeaderBean.header}" assignTo="#{Home.subHeaderName}"/>

</a4j:commandLink>
</rich:panel>
 </c:forEach>
 </h:panelGrid>
  <%--SubHeader Detail Panel--%>
  <h:panelGrid rendered="#{Home.subHeaderDetailedContentPanelRendered}" id="subHeaderGrid">
  <h:outputText id="detailedContent" value="#{Home.subHeaderDetailedContent}" escape="false"/>
 <f:verbatim><center></f:verbatim>                    
 <a4j:commandLink id="backLinks" value="#{platform.backButtonLabel}"
  action="#{Home.backButtonAction}"
                                                                                reRender="leftOutputPanel"/>
 <f:verbatim></center></f:verbatim>
                                               </h:panelGrid>                                                            
                                                        </a4j:outputPanel>                                                       
</rich:tab>
</c:forEach>
```

How can i achieve that?Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can not determine the id of the tabe panels rendered in the forEach loop you have to rerender the panelGrid *detailGrid*. Take care to cache all values shown on the tabs in your managed beans. If you do so no database call is required and rerendering of all tabs is fast.